# Supremum of family of measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory

This is a problem from the book Measure, Integration and Real Analysis by Axler.

Give an example of measurable space $(X,S)$ and a family ${f_t}$ $t$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$ such that each $f_t$ is $S$ measurable function from $X$ to $[0,1]$ but the function $f(x)  = \sup\{f_t(x)\}$ is not $S$ measurable.

If it would have been sequence of functions then $f$ can be shown to be $S$ measurable.

Comment: Easy measurable functions are $f(x)=0$ except at one point where $f(x)=1$.  Try using suprema of those.

Comment: Isn' t the suprema function constant f=1 then? Is the one point dependent on t?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(X, S)$ be the space of Lebesgue-measurable sets. Let $N$ be a non-Lebesgue measurable set. Then,

$$1_N = \sup_{x \in N} 1_{\{x\}}$$

is non-measurable, where $1_A$ is the indicator function for $A \subset X$.

Comment: Can you give an example without using the lebesgue measurable sets.We arent introduced to that yet

Comment: Yes. The same example generalizes. Let $(X, S)$ be any measurable space such that some $N \subset X$ is not in $S$, and $S$ contains all the singeltons $\{x\}$, $x \in X$.

Comment: More concretely, let $X$ be any uncountable set, and let $S$ be the sigma-algebra of subsets of $X$ that are either countable or have countable complement. Then let $N$ be any uncountable set with an uncountable complement.