# Exercise 29 on p.40 in Exercises 2B in "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

I am reading "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.
The following exercise is Exercise 29 on p.40 in Exercises 2B in this book.

> Exercise 29
> Give an example of a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{S})$ and a family $\{f_t\}_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ such that each $f_ t$ is an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function from $X$ to $[0,1]$, but the function $f:X\to [0,1]$ defined by $$f(x)=\sup\{f_t(x):t\in\mathbb{R}\}$$ is not $\mathcal{S}$-measurable.
> [*Compare this exercise to 2.53, where the index set is $\mathbb{Z}^+$ rather than $\mathbb{R}$.*]

I was not able to solve Exercise 29.
I found [aduh's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3791328/384082).
It is not necessary to be $N=\mathbb{R}$ in aduh's answer.
I think the following solution is a special case of aduh's answer.
Is the following solution ok?
And I want to know another solution for Exercise 29.

> Let $X:=\mathbb{C}.$
> Let $\mathcal{S}:=\{E\subset X:E\text{ is countable or }X\setminus E\text{ is countable}\}.$
> Then, $(X,\mathcal{S})$ is a measurable space. (See Example 2.28 on p.28 and Exercise 2 in Exercises 2B on p.38 in the book.)
> Let $\{f_t\}_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ be a family such that each $f_t$ is a function from $X$ to $[0,1]$ such that $f_t(x):=\chi_{\{t\}}(x)$ for every $x\in X.$
> Let $t\in\mathbb{R}.$
> Let $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a Borel set.
> If $0\in B$ and $1\in B$, then $f_t^{-1}(B)=X\in\mathcal{S}.$
> If $0\in B$ and $1\notin B$, then $f_t^{-1}(B)=X\setminus\{t\}\in\mathcal{S}.$
> If $0\notin B$ and $1\in B$, then $f_t^{-1}(B)=\{t\}\in\mathcal{S}.$
> If $0\notin B$ and $1\notin B$, then $f_t^{-1}(B)=\emptyset\in\mathcal{S}.$
> So, $f_t$ is an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function.
> $\{f_t(x):t\in\mathbb{R}\}=\{0,1\}$ if $x\in\mathbb{R}.$
> $\{f_t(x):t\in\mathbb{R}\}=\{0\}$ if $x\in X\setminus\mathbb{R}.$
> So, $\sup\{f_t(x):t\in\mathbb{R}\}=1$ if $x\in\mathbb{R}.$
> So, $\sup\{f_t(x):t\in\mathbb{R}\}=0$ if $x\in X\setminus\mathbb{R}.$
> Therefore, $f(x):=\sup\{f_t(x):t\in\mathbb{R}\}=\chi_{\mathbb{R}}(x).$
> $\{1\}$ is a Borel set and $f^{-1}(\{1\})=\chi_{\mathbb{R}}^{-1}(\{1\})=\mathbb{R}\notin\mathcal{S}.$
> So, $f$ is not $\mathcal{S}$-measurable.

Comment: Can't you just take any non-measurable $f:\mathbf{R}\to[0,1]$ (setting $(X,\mathcal{S})=(\mathbf{R},\lambda))$ and decompose it in $f_t$ with $f_t(t)=f(t)$ and $f(t')=0$ for $t'\neq t$?

Comment: Following the example given in your posting, choose $x_0\in E$, $E$ a non-Borel measurable set in $\mathbb{R}$,and set $f_t=f_{x_0}$ for all $t\in E^c$.

Comment: @fweth Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thank you very much for your answer.